# Binary, Octal, Hexadecimal to Decimal program

Tags: c++

so I had this assignment to write a C++ program that converts binary, octal or hexadecimal number to decimal, which I did, and here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

long two2ten(string s)
{
    int m = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        m = 2 * m + (s[i] - '0');
    }
    return m;
}

long oct2dec(int n)
{
    long int m = 0, i = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        m = m + (n % 10)* pow(8, i++);
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return m;
}
long hex2dec(string s)
{
    long result = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
    {
        if (s[i] >= 48 && s[i] <= 57)
        {
            result += (s[i] - 48)*pow(16, s.length() - i - 1);
        }
        else if (s[i] >= 65 && s[i] <= 70) {
            result += (s[i] - 55)*pow(16, s.length() - i - 1);
        }
        else if (s[i] >= 97 && s[i] <= 102) {
            result += (s[i] - 87)*pow(16, s.length() - i - 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int k, n;
    string s;
    while (cin >> k)
    {
        if (k == 2)
        {
            cin >> s;
            cout << two2ten(s) << endl;
        }
        else if (k == 8)
        {
            cin >> n;
            cout << oct2dec(n) << endl;
        }
        else if (k == 16)
        {
            cin >> s;
            cout << hex2dec(s) << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cin >> n;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, it works perfectly fine for me, however it gives Compilation error to my teacher (and he doesn't say why). I've been hitting my head on the wall for a few days now and I still can't get what could be wrong. Could somebody help me with that please?

Comment: If he doesn't say why, that's hardly fair. How do you compile it? Maybe we can suggest if you use some unusual option.

Comment: May be ask him the compiler and OS he is using?

Comment: What are your compiler/options? What are your teacher's?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please avoid using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Also there's really no reason to use the *floating point* `pow` function for conversions (or bothering with the string lengths). Or to need two cases for the hexadecimal conversion as you could easily convert letters [to upper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) or [to lower](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) case.

Comment: Okay, your teacher doesn't say _why_ your code gives him an error, but did he tell you what _the error message_ is?

Comment: If you are compiling from command line with `g++`, use `-Wall -Werror` options.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I gave it a shot, but it still compiled.

Comment: I propose closing this question. No errors on [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ce578e58bb33448) or [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3a5143e81ed16ac). On VS2015 I get warnings for `conversion from 'double' to 'long', possible loss of data`, but again, no errors.

Comment: I think you should demand the compiler version and options.  If the same compiler version and options work for you and not for him, then you should demand the error message.

Comment: @flatmouse That could be the issue then.  If the teachers is treating warnings as errors then it would be an error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are being asked to guess what the compilation error is.

Comment: @flatmouse: Agreed.  To the OP: This is not your fault, but this is a question and answer site where the principle aim is to have a ready-made list of answers to questions.  We can't answer without more info.

Comment: @NathanOliver, true and it is an L2 warning no less.  That could be it, but I don't believe we can answer the question as written.

Comment: Not a problem as such, but you can follow the pattern from `two2ten` - `m = base * m + digit` - for all bases.

Comment: @ilim This is the strictest level of g++. It enables all warnings, and treats them as errors. At this point there is no way to answer your question without talking to your teacher. I am voting to close the question.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, he doesn't give us any information on how he's compiling nor the compile error (neither the numbers he's testing). I know it's frustrating, thanks for the help tho!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that when calling those pow() functions, implicit conversion happened for the second parameter (from size_t to double). Adding static_cast should help.

To see the problem yourself, compile your code with

```
-pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion
```